# Trigger phpMyAdmin using variables

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger in phpMyAdmin, where I can modify the value of a field whenever it is inserted depending of a field name. I am using this syntax

```
CREATE TRIGGER lawyers AFTER INSERT ON wp_posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '<!--:en-->&nbsp;<!--:--><!--:ES-->&nbsp;<!--:-->'      
WHERE ID = NEW.ID AND post_type = 'lawyers';
END
```

but I can't make it work, it says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write such a trigger anyway, updating the same table you're inserting into.  When I tested your trigger, I got this:

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'wp_posts' in stored function/trigger
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored 
function/trigger.
```

The following should do the same thing as your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lawyers BEFORE INSERT ON wp_posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.post_type = 'lawyers') THEN
  SET NEW.post_content = '<!--:en-->&nbsp;<!--:--><!--:ES-->&nbsp;<!--:-->';
 END IF;
END
```

---

Answer:  phpMyAdmin requires a special mode if you use CREATE TRIGGER or CREATE PROCEDURE.

- Below the SQL Query box, there's a small form field labeled **Delimiter**.  Set this to `$$`.
- Enter your CREATE TRIGGER statement and terminate it with `$$` after the last `END`.
- Click the **Go** button.

See http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Trigger

This is analogous to using the [`DELIMITER` built-in command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) in the mysql command-line client.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I've tried your query but I keep getting the same error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`. Do you think its a server issue?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Try `SELECT VERSION();`